# Do I need to call .Dispose() on both of these XmlDataSource objects? "CA2000 Dispose objects before losing scope" tells me to .Dispose() it

Tags: c#, dispose, xmldatasource

In my extremely simplified code sample my Foo() method calls `GetXmlDataSource()` which returns an `XmlDataSource`. CA2000 says that I should `Dispose()` an XmlDatasource before losing scope.

- Should I wrap each `XmlDataSource` in a using statement?
- Should I use `try`/`catch`/`finally` in the lower one and a `using` in the upper one?
- Do I effectively have two `XmlDataSource` objects, one in the upper method and one in the lower method?

I'm a little fuzzy on language behavior in this one and I want to be a good boy.

```
void Foo()
{
    XmlDataSource xds = GetXmlDataSource();
}

XmlDataSource GetXmlDataSource()
{
    XmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
    return xmlDataSource;
}
```

Comment: your last question: no they are reference type so its only one.

Comment: You should dispose the object in your `Foo` method when you're done with it. If code analysis complains about `GetXmlDataSource`, try naming it `CreateXmlDataSource` and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I wrap each XmlDataSource in a using statement?

If it goes out of scope inside that method, yes, you should. You can also use `using` on variables coming from other methods by the way.

> Should I use try/catch/finally in the lower one?

Yes and no. The `XmlDataSource` shouldn't be disposed since you intend to use it in the other method. You should dispose it if you have an exception that will prevent the variable to be passed along.

> Should I use using in the upper one?

Yes, you should. This code will do the job.

```
using (XmlDataSource xds = GetXmlDataSource())
{ }
```

> Do I effectively have two `XmlDataSource` objects, one in the upper method and one in the lower method?

No, you have one. That is why you shouldn't dispose the lower one. There is a reference passed from one method to another.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You said, "You can also use `using` on variables coming from other methods by the way." What do you mean?

Comment: Like this one: `using (XmlDataSource xds = GetXmlDataSource())`.

Answer (score 1):

1) only wrap the final usage in a using.
2) no, a using is enough (note that the underlying implementation of using **is** a try/finally).
3) you have only one object instance.